# TinyMCE text editor stop working with chrome new version 115

Tags: google-chrome, text, tinymce

In our website we are using TinyMCE text editor. The functionality was working fine in 114 version of chrome but same code start breaking once we upgraded Chrome browse from 114 to 115. Did anyone faced same problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Somehow we have fixed the code by putting "window.onload event" some places. But this is not the perfect solution.